# jquery and json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, couchdb

I stop 2 days and looking for the answer,
This is what my data looks like:

The field rows have this data:

```
rows :
[
   [
       "1",
       "test1",
       "pw85798",
       "GM",
       "38475786",
       "yr",
       "m",
       "20-11-1972",
       "100",
       "test@yahoo.com"
   ],
   [
       "11",
       "test2",
       "pw78423786",
       "media",
       "",
       "yrer",
       "m",
       "11-05-1990",
       "1",
       "yuterui@yahoo.com"
   ],
```

I have 2 textboxes: `usetext` and `pwstext`
I want my loop to take the 2 values on the texts and look inside the array if `usrtext = "test1"` and `pswtext = "pw85798"`. Then `<div>` will appear. If not, alert `"error"`
I need this code to go on.

I tried this:

```
db.openDoc(id, {
    success:function (result) {
        // Update revision input field

        $("#revision").val(result.rows[0,1]);
```

It returns all the first indexes:

```
1, test1, pw85798, GM, , 38475786, yr, m, ...
```

Comment: Are you saying that oyu have a JSON array of data that you want to compare to data entered by a user?

Comment: So in those 2 days, what did you try?

Comment: Also, security doesn't appear to be a concern for you so you might as well just have a "let me in" button

Comment: looks like your problem is hard to be expressed in an easy-to-understand way.

Comment: "_I need this code to go on_" search in google :)

Comment: What @musefan is trying to say: If you handle all authorization on the client (browser) side, anyone can easily "hack" into your site.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Trying to say? That's *exactly* what I said... just in a different, hmm... *'accent'*

Comment: @musefan: Yea, maybe _"trying to say"_ wasn't that accurate :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend and you should NOT use this code.

But I think this works as you want it to work, though it's really unadvised. Use it at your own risk.

I'm iterating over your json data and matching the user name and password to the content of the textboxes. I'm really not comfortable providing this lol.

'q' is a javascript object containing your json data.

```
q.forEach(function(item)    {
    if($("#user").val() == item[1] && $("#pass").val() == item[2])    {
        alert(1);
        // do something
    } else {
        alert(2);
        // do something else
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaA84/)

Comment: `q` is JSON data? or javascript object?

Comment: It's a javascript object, updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: _"JSON data"_ --> _"JavaScript Object Notation data"_.
JSON is a _"open standard designed for human-readable data interchange."_ It's not data, it's a way to format the data.

Comment: +1: It works, and well done for advising against it. Though I would be tempted to have used `result.rows` instead of `q` to make it more clear to the OP. Also, you know JSFiddle has a "TidyUp" button right? (just a personal thing)

Comment: HAHA I had no idea of that button. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: i'm new on jquery , what do u mean 'q' is a javascript object containing your json data.i need the syntax

Comment: @amrnavy: Try replacing `q` with `result.rows` and see if it works

Comment: thank you ppl ill try , by the way if we take about Security is there a way when any user make save page some files didnt download with the page

Comment: sorry if it look amateur , i want that code fire when i click submit

Comment: @amrnavy: What you need to remember is that javascript is a client-side process. Any user can modify your javascript code. For example, they could change `if(user == x && pass == y)` to `if(true)` and bypass any checks. Typically you should be using a server-side technology to authenticate, such as ASP.Net or PHP

Comment: @musefanok: i get the point but first come first i need to do that code and i'll edit it cus i have a issue between php and couchdb , i make upload image by php and work greet on my localhost server but when i push it to my couchdb it didnt work and say method not all even after i change CORS on my couchdb config , it need some search to solve that.

Comment: @amrnavy one step at a time. You should open a thread for each of your problems. Don't forget to include some code and what you tried so far for each one so you don't get downvoted

Answer (score 0):

this is my page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="databases"></div>
<form>
  <p>
  <input name="usrtext" type="text" id="usrtext"/>
  <br>
  <input  name="pswtext" type="text" id="pswtext"/>
  </p>
  <input id="test" type="text" name="test"/>
  <p><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="login"/>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
  <script>
var db = $.couch.db("aabc");
var id = "iams";
    //$('#login').submit(function()  {
    db.openDoc(id, {
    success:function (result) {
          result.rows.forEach(function(item)    {
          if($("#usrtext").val() == item[1] && $("#pswtext").val() == item[2])    
           {
            alert(1);
            $("#test").val(result._id);
            }
       else {
            alert(2);
            $("#test").val(result._rev);
        // do something else
            }
           });

        }
    //})
 });
  </script>
</html>
```

my json data

```
rows:[
  ["1","test1","12345","GM","7847427","alix","m","20-05-1975","100","test@yahoo.com"],
  ["11","test2","54321","media","","tom","m","","1","reret@yahoo.com"]
  ]
```

when page loading alert(2) fire many times as my rows count if i had 5 its appear 5 times and val(result._rev); is work
but if i inter the right value like test1 and 12345 ,alert (2) is appear not alert(1)

Comment: console.log('Testing '+ item[1] + ' / ' +item[2]); it back "Testing test1 / 12345" and its right but still didnt fire alert(1)

Comment: at last it works but still counting on loop and when the field is right alert1 fire but still looping and if the field on index 4 , three alert2 fire i need just if it didnt there one alert say no user

Comment: i handle that by making a flag , thank u @cr0ss and musefan , u show me the way